# Why is my word counter sometimes off by one?

Tags: java, string, file, bufferedreader, filereader

Most of the time it works correctly. Rarely it counts off by one. Any guess?

```
public static int countWords(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();

        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] strArray= line.split("\\s+");
            for (int i=0; i<strArray.length;i++){
                strList.add(strArray[i]);
            }
        }
        return strList.size();

    }
```

Particularly in the example below it gives 3 instead of 2:

```
\n
             k
```

Comment: Do you consider `\n` to be a word? I would think `k` is the only *word* in your example.

Comment: I guess it is counting new line as 1, tab as 2nd and then k as 3rd ;)

Comment: how can I fix it? @BilboBaggins

Comment: You're iterating over an array to add the results to a list to return the size??

Comment: You need to close your resources.

Comment: Try creating a set/map or some other data structure that would hold all the key/words which you don't want to count, or another way is you remove all those unwanted "words" from your string first and then find words from it.

Comment: *Particularly in the example below it gives 3 instead of 2* Ok. What are the values of these three elements ? Is it `[, \n, k]` ? Is there any empty line before `\n` ? Is it `\n[tab][newLine][tab]k` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Java 8**, you can use Streams and filter what you consider as a "word". For example:

```
    List<String> l = Files.lines(Paths.get("files/input.txt")) // Read all lines of your input text
            .flatMap(s->Stream.of(s.split("\\s+"))) // Split each line by white spaces
            .filter(s->s.matches("\\w")) // Keep only the "words" (you can change here as you want)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Put the stream in a List
```

In this specific case, it will output `[k]`.

You can of course do the same in **Java 7** by adapting your code and add this condition in your `for` loop:

```
if(strArray[i].matches("\\w"))
    strList.add(strArray[i]); // Keep only the "words" - again, use your own criteria
```

It is just more cumbersome.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Why do you drag streams to such simple problem?

Comment: The file is a stream of lines and the lines are streams of words. No need to use `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` or to do explicit loops. The result is shorter and more readable.

Comment: But you read the whole file into memory. If file is large, reading it line-by-line is better. Your code will consume much more memory.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the second line is split into two string, "" and "k". See the code below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "           k";
    String[] array = str.split("\\\s+");
    System.out.println("length of array is " + array.length); // length is 2
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); //array is [, k]
}
```